# SyncAdapter onPerformSync get current location

Tags: android-syncadapter, location-services

When `onPerformSync` occurs I need the current location but I do not want to set up a separate service that is constantly active requesting location because my `SyncAdapter` period exponentially backs off such that the periods between syncs could be many hours apart. It would be wasteful to have location requests running between each sync.

I am planning on using a `GoogleApiClient` and `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates` then `Thread.sleep(###)` the `onPerformSync` thread until a location is found.

However I have read that `requestLocationUpdates` needs to be called on the [main looper and that it makes callbacks on that thread](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener)) in which case I expect will it fail to return location results because I am sleeping on the thread which called it.

Will I need to start my own looper thread?

Is there another/better way to get current location from `onPerformSync`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my fears were not justified, my method does work without error. I have put together a handy example class below in case anyone else wants to do this:

```
public class cSyncLocation  implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener
{   

    // =======================================================
    // private vars
    // =======================================================
    private GoogleApiClient moGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest moLocationRequest;
    private Location moCurrentLocation; 
    private static final int kTIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS = 2500;

    // =======================================================
    // public static vars
    // =======================================================

    // =======================================================
    // public methods
    // =======================================================

    public void Start(Context oContext)
    {
        if (moGoogleApiClient == null)
        {
            moGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(oContext)
                                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                                .build();
        }
        if (moLocationRequest == null)
        {
            moLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

            moLocationRequest.setInterval(1);
            moLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1);
            moLocationRequest.setInterval(1);
            moLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        }
        // Start the connection
        if (moGoogleApiClient != null) 
        {
            if (!moGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() && !moGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
                moGoogleApiClient.connect();
            else if (moCurrentLocation == null)
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(moGoogleApiClient, moLocationRequest, this);

        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (moGoogleApiClient != null && moGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(moGoogleApiClient, this);
        if (moGoogleApiClient != null)
            moGoogleApiClient.disconnect();     
    }

    public Location GetLocationBlocking(Context oContext)
    {
        if (moCurrentLocation == null)
        {
            intTimeout = kTIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS;
            Start(oContext);
            while(intTimeout > 0 && aFrmLocationActivity.IsLastLocationExpired(oContext))
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                intTimeout -= 100;
            }
            Stop();
        }
        return moCurrentLocation;
    }

    // =======================================================
    // Location API Events
    // =======================================================

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location oLocation) 
    {
        if (oLocation != null)
        {
            moCurrentLocation = oLocation;
        }
    }

    // =======================================================
    // Google API Connection Events
    // =======================================================


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) 
    {
        // Connected to Google Play services! The good stuff goes here.
        if (moGoogleApiClient != null)
        {
            Location oLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(moGoogleApiClient);
            if (oLocation != null)
                moCurrentLocation = oLocation;
            else
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(moGoogleApiClient, moLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) 
    {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) 
    {
        //...
    }       


}
```

How to use it, in your `onPerformSync` method call it like this

```
cSyncLocation oSyncLocation = new cSyncLocation();
Location oLocation = oSyncLocation.GetLocationBlocking(getContext());
```

Obviously you will want to add some exception handling and deal with null location result.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, `onLocationChanged` has never been called.

Comment: Check you have uses-permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in the Manifest. If you are targeting and running on Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher then you will need to ask the user for permission to access location in the UI part of your app, once granted it should work on the syncadapter too. But maybe it is just timing out before finding the location.

Comment: I tried to receive location with the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission. When I changed it to the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION the problem has been fixed.